# call CellContentDoubleClick event from button click in c#

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a CellContentDoubleClick event on my `DataGridView` "todos_pacientes" and what I want to do is to simulate the `CellContentDoubleClick` event on my button, how do I call it from my button click event ?

Here's my code:

```
private void toolSt_modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

        }                    


private void Datagrid_todos_pacientes_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 

 {
   id_paciente=Convert.ToInt32(Datagrid_todos_pacientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());  

   datos_paciente datos = new datos_paciente();
   datos.Show();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private void toolSt_modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int col = Datagrid_todos_pacientes.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int row = Datagrid_todos_pacientes.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    Datagrid_todos_pacientes_CellContentDoubleClick(sender, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(col, row));
}
```